# allocate a memory for a matrix (n*1)

Tags: c++, memory-management, matrix

I want to create a matrix of n*1 (a matrix of one column. `n` can be any integer)

I think It should be something like:

```
int mat[][1];
cin >> n;
*mat = new int[n]*;
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: A matrix that has only one column is a vector. Why don't you just use `ìnt mat[n]` ?

Comment: There are many SO questions on this topic, search for dynamic memory allocation or variable length array.

Comment: but I want it to be a matrix (two pointers). I know how to define a vector, but I want a matrix.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105653/int-matrix-with-pointers-in-c-memory-allocation-confusion?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare your matrix as:

```
int mat[][1];
```

It means that you are not doing dynamic memory allocation.

You should do the following:

```
int **mat = new int*[n]; //n is number of rows
for (int i = 0; i < n ;++i)
{
   mat[i] = new int[1];
}
```

Anyway, you should prefer to use `std::vector` instead of using dynamic allocated arrays, especially when you have only 1 column.

Answer (score 1):

```
int * * mat = new int * [ n ];
```

Comment: thank you but I want a matrix that each row has a pointer to int.